# What are const-class and const-method-type opcodes for? What java code generates them?

Tags: java, bytecode, dalvik

I'm creating a tool for post processing of dalvik applications. For tests I want to create code that will contain every opcode. I'm having problems understanding what  const-class and const-method-type opcodes do. The definitions in dalvik's official documentation are not clarifying the issue for me.

> const-class
>
> Move a reference to the class specified by the given index into the
>   specified register. In the case where the indicated type is primitive,
>   this will store a reference to the primitive type's degenerate class.

What is reference to the class? This is not reference to an object as far as I know.

Same with

> const-method-type
>
> Move a reference to the method prototype specified by the given index
>   into the specified register.

As far as I understand this is not function pointer. Function pointer is handled by

> const-method-handle
>
> Move a reference to the method handle specified by the given index
>   into the specified register.

**My question is:**

What are const-class and const-method-type used for? What kind of java code would generate those opcodes in Dalvik?

Maybe it's worth mentioning that my java experience is rather low - I'm c++ kind of guy.

Comment: reference: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/dalvik-bytecode

Comment: Isn't it the one I quoted? As I said this doesn't seem very descriptive. At least for me it's too vague

Comment: Of cause it's what you quoted. I wondered why you did not include it, so I did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`const-class` can be generated when you refer to a the class property of an object. e.g. `Class cls = MyObject.class`.

As far as I know, method handles and types aren't generated by java code. You can reference them using reflection, but I don't think doing so will actually generate the `const-method-type` or `const-method-handle` instructions

They are supporting cast for `invoke-custom`, which is primarily intended for use by other languages that get compiled to java bytecode and eventually dalvik bytecode.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explanation about const-class. Indeed it does work. Could you also elaborate a bit more on the const-method and the paragraph with invoke-custom? I'm afraid my java knowledge is too little to understand those last 2 paragraphs :(

Comment: There are other languages that get compiled to java/dalvik bytecode. invoke-custom (and the related const-method-type and const-method-handle) was added to help support some unique use cases that these other languages need, but they aren't used by java itself.

Comment: Im marking this answer. Could you please put all the information from your comment in your answer too? I believe that would make a good reading for other users in the future.